# module with two functions

Tags: function, python-3.x

Trying to create a module with two functions, one that calculates the area and the circumference and the second functions will find the diameter to three decimal places.

```
def main():
    import math
    def area(radius):
    print(math.pi * radius**2)
def circumference(radius):
    print(2*math.pi * radius)
main()
```

each time i run this program, nothing is printing out, it's just a blank page. I have changed this program several ways and still a blank screen., x

Comment: That should be a SyntaxError.  Is `area()` meant to be a function?  If it is, it should have some code.  If it isn't, remove that line.

Answer (score 0):

first i dont know because your use `import math` inside of the function, now when you call a `main()` the result is None, because there is not an argument to sub-function,

```
from math import pi
def main(argument):
    def area(argument = argument):
        print(math.pi * radius **2)

def circumference(radius):
    print((2*math.pi)* radius)
```

remember, use return to the funcionts o else you could to find a `None` as result of the functions

```
def circumference(radius):
    result = ((2*math.pi)) * radius)
    return result
```